# Allow users to create post without logging in?

Tags: users, authentication, multi-author

I have this project that requires guests to normally write a post without requiring them to be a user. By normally, I mean they can write posts by going to the posts edit screen like a normal user would do but with limitations. Is this possible?

Comment: http://voodoopress.com/how-to-post-from-your-front-end-with-no-plugin/

Comment: Yes it is. Now if you want a better answer you should give more details about what exactly are you trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

the easiest way is to use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/guest-posts/

> Offer your blog guests or unregistered blog readers an opportunity to post on your WordPress blog without registering themselves.
>   Guest Posts will help you to create a strong interaction and engagement with your blog readers.
>
> This plugin will create a form where your guests can submit their posts.
>   The posts will be saved directly into your WordPress database and will show up in your WordPress Dashboard as pending.
>   You can then review and approve them as needed.
>
> It will save authors Name and email as custom field, so you will be able to display authors name and give them a credit back with some simple tweaks into your theme.
>
> You can also show a custom Thank You message after submitting the post.
>
> The plugin is simple to install and use. Even a very novice user can install and use the plugin. And I'm sure you are good than that. ;)
>   No need to edit any code.
>   For a easy installation guide checkout the Installation tab above.
>
> You can style the form if you wish. We have used just one class called "guest-posts". To style the form add CSS for the "guest-posts" class and it's sub elements into your theme.
>
> Upcoming Features
>
> - User selectable category
> - Captcha validation
> - A nice Admin Panel

after installing it, create a new page and put the guest posts shortcode in it `[gest-posts author=id]` where id is the userid of that would be marked as the author of the posts. You can create a new user and name it **Anonymous** or **Guest**, you can just write `[gest-posts]`.

You can create a custom Thank you page and set it via thanks attribute.
Example: `[guest-posts thanks="http://yoursite.com/thanks"]`
By default it will take your gusts to the home page after submitting the post.

Comment: > This plugin has been closed and is no longer available for download.

Comment: following your note @Zhigalin-ReinstateCMs I see this a good replacement: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-submitted-posts/ I don't know if I should update the answer.